# If $f\left(x\right)=\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{2}\left(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-x^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)$ , $x>0$ then $\int xf\left(x\right)$ is?

Tags: limits, indefinite-integrals

Tried bringing $n^{2}$ to the Denominator and splitting but no luck just give me a clue on how to start approach

Comment: Did you mean $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n^{2}\left(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-x^{\frac{1}{n+1}}\right)?$$

Comment: @MarioG oopse sorry will update the question asap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry can't actually add a comment so writing here:
Putting.
$$
n=\frac{1}{t} \Rightarrow \lim_{t\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^{t}-x^{\frac{t}{t+1}}}{t^{2}}
$$
now applying l'hospital rule twice to get $$ f(x) = ln(x) $$
Now you can proceed

Comment: Lol i kept differentiating wtr to x , my bad , anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
$$
x^{1/n} = 1 + \frac{\log x}{n} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\log^2 x}{n^2} + \ldots
$$
for $x>0$. Collect and simplify.

Comment: This comes from the fact that $x=e^{\ln x}$ and $e^t=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{t^k}{k!}$